# Стилизация select и option

Tags: select, optional

Всем привет!
Нашел код для стилизации select и option.
Но он работает только для одного select.
Кто может подсказать почему?
Спасибо.

```js
const selectSingle = document.querySelector('.__select');
const selectSingle_title = selectSingle.querySelector('.__select__title');
const selectSingle_labels = selectSingle.querySelectorAll('.__select__label');

// Toggle menu
selectSingle_title.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if ('active' === selectSingle.getAttribute('data-state')) {
    selectSingle.setAttribute('data-state', '');
  } else {
    selectSingle.setAttribute('data-state', 'active');
  }
});

// Close when click to option
for (let i = 0; i < selectSingle_labels.length; i++) {
  selectSingle_labels[i].addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    selectSingle_title.textContent = evt.target.textContent;
    selectSingle.setAttribute('data-state', '');
  });
}

// Reset title
const reset = document.querySelector('.reset');
reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
  selectSingle_title.textContent = selectSingle_title.getAttribute('data-default');
});
```

```css
.__select {
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
  &:last-child {
    width: 120px;
  }

  &[data-state="active"] {
    .__select__title {
      &::before {
        transform: translate(-3px, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
      }

      &::after {
        transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
      }
    }

    .__select__content {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .__select__label+.__select__input+.__select__label {
      max-height: 40px;
      border-top-width: 1px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="__select mr-2 mb-2" data-state="">
              <div class="__select__title" data-default="Option 0">Name</div>
              <div class="__select__content">
                <input id="singleSelect00" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" />
                <label for="singleSelect00" class="__select__label">Name</label>
                <input id="singleSelect00" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" />
                <label for="singleSelect00" class="__select__label">Name</label>
                <input id="singleSelect11" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" />
                <label for="singleSelect11" class="__select__label">Name</label>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что

```
const selectSingle = document.querySelector('.__select');
const selectSingle_title = selectSingle.querySelector('.__select__title');
```

Возвращают только 1-й найденный элемент. Чтобы это работало для нескольких элементов, надо выбирать через `querySelectorAll` и потом в цикле для каждого элемента присваивать слушатель событий `addEventListener`, как у Вас сделано для `selectSingle_labels[i]`

Comment: Спб.Еще вопрос. Как сделать так, чтоб при клике на любов место список закривался?

Comment: Клик на любое место чего?

Comment: На любое место HTML.